# Variable doesn't work on appendChild

Tags: javascript

The following is the code that I am currently working with. On the fly I am creating a form and sending it's values to another server for processing. When I use the variable for the value it doesn't work but when I hardcode the values it works. Please see below.

This code contains variable assigned to the value which doesn't work.

```
var vfirstname, vlastname;
vfirstname = "Stack";
vlastname = "Overflow";

var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
mapForm.target = "_blank";    
mapForm.method = "POST";
mapForm.action = "https://www.example.com/api/details/";

var firstname = document.createElement("input");
var lastname = document.createElement("input");

firstname.type = "text"; firstname.name = "firstname"; firstname.value = vfirstname;
lastname.type = "text"; lastname.name = "lastname"; lastname.value = vlastname;
mapForm.appendChild( firstname );
mapForm.appendChild( lastname );
document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
mapForm.submit();
```

but when I hard code the values it works

```
firstname.type = "text"; firstname.name = "firstname"; firstname.value = "Stack";
lastname.type = "text"; lastname.name = "lastname"; lastname.value = "Overflow";
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p7fz7w0o/

Comment: So you use same code on both your tests with only difference using hard coded values works as expected but with variables fails ? it does not make sense. Just ensure if your variables has values. And wrap that code into a function to encapsulate your variables against global scope

Comment: How are you receiving the data server-side?

Comment: This seems fishy/ Is there any other context around your code? There's no reason it should make a difference.